# Basic web app saying "hello, world."

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I am watching one tutorial to get a basic web app saying "hello, world"
But for some reason I don't understand, I am getting this
"The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request."

This is what I did.
1. I installed Google App Engine SDK for python.
2. I created two files like this:

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

I didnt write these. These were given in google app engine website.

and I tried two different methods to run it.

1. Using terminal
   in the folder where the two files are:

I used this command: dev_appserver.py .
and this is what I get:

```
INFO     2016-04-02 04:28:02,071 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-04-02 04:28:02,949 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2016-04-02 04:28:02,982 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50345
INFO     2016-04-02 04:28:02,988 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-04-02 04:28:02,989 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

and when I enter "http://localhost:8000" on chrome, I get this error msg:
"The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request."

and this is the error msg I get on terminal

```
ERROR    2016-04-02 04:43:47,109 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named helloworld
INFO     2016-04-02 04:43:47,114 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2016-04-02 04:43:47,602 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named helloworld
INFO     2016-04-02 04:43:47,606 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

2. Using google app engine launcher
   I created a new application and this gave me all the files I needed.
   So I just ran it.
   It shows me a port number, and when I tried that on chrome,
   "http://localhost:8000"
   I get the same error as the first msg.

What is it that I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: @Ook yes, I've tried that and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you've  named your module `main.py`, but told the GAE server to look for a module named `helloworld`. That module doesn't exist, so the site can't be loaded.

Either rename your `main.py` file to `helloworld.py`, or change `app.yaml` to point to `main.app` instead of `helloworld.app`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem.

Comment: Do you happen to know this command: "dev_appserver.py -p 8888 ." According to the tutorial it says "-p" is to run it on a different port, but when I tried this I get this compiling error msg:  "dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -p" What should I do?

Comment: The [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) I found by googling suggests using `--port=8888` rather than `-p 8888`. Perhaps your tutorial is out of date?

Answer (score -2):

webapp2 doesnt have a good introduction. if you're new to web frameworks i would adivse you to start through this one.

https://github.com/iogf/untwisted

It is an event-driven library that has a set of plugins implemented and one of the is a micro web framework whose design is similar to flask but much faster.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with webapp2 at all?

Comment: It might be a fine framework but because of it's design it is completely unsuitable for traditional appengine

Comment: yeah. i think that is viable. why do you think it is not traditional for appengine?